# Faye doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, faye

I'm writing a simple real-time chat, so I decided to use web-sockets. I used `gem 'faye-rails'`. Web console shows that it works `POST http://khersonchat.herokuapp.com/faye [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 170ms]` but when I send a message there's an error: `While loading the page connection ws://khersonchat.herokuapp.com/faye was broken`(*translated from Russian*). So when I send a message, the whole page still reloads, and I need to reload a page to see other people's messages sent.

**`messages_controller.rb`**:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        if current_user
            @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
            if @message.save
                flash[:success] = 'Message sent'
            else
                flash[:error] = 'Oops, an error :('
            end
            format.html {redirect_to root_path}
            format.js
        else
            format.html {redirect_to root_path}
            format.js {render nothing: true}
        end
    end
end
```

**`application.js`**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require faye
//= require messages
//= require_self
//= require turbolinks
```

**`messages.coffee`**:

```
window.client = new Faye.Client('/faye')

jQuery ->
    $('#new_message').submit ->
        $(this).find("input[type='submit']").val('Sending...').prop('disabled', true)
    try
        client.unsubscribe('/messages')
    catch
        console?.log "Can't unsubscribe"

    client.subscribe '/messages', (payload) ->
        $('#messages').find('.media-list').append(payload.message) if payload.message
```

**`create.js.erb`**

```
publisher = client.publish('/messages', {
    message: '<%= j render @message %>'
});

publisher.callback(function() {
     $("#message_body").val('');
     $("#new_message").find("input[type='submit']").val('Send').prop('disabled', false)
});

publisher.errback(function() {
    alert('Oops, an error');
});
```

https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/chatclone.git - up-to-date source code

**important!** the chat authenticates via `omniauth`, using a social network *Vkontakte(vk.com)*, so the version stored in git has the access to localhost

Comment: It seems that Faye just doesn't let the messages to publish, and I have completely no idea what's the matter :( double-triple-checked everything, but it simply doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with **Csrf Protection**, so the topic continues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389909/conflict-between-faye-and-csrf-protection)